# Regular expression code to remove strings sepesrted by "+++$+++" from a text file?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file from which I want to remove all all the characters sparated by the `+++$+++`

Here's the file:

```
L666256 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?

L666257 +++$+++ u9030 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ DURNFORD +++$+++ Good ones, yes, Mr Vereker. Gentlemen who can ride and shoot

L666369 +++$+++ u9030 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ DURNFORD +++$+++ Your orders, Mr Vereker?
L666370 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ I'm to take the Sikali with the main column to the river

L666371 +++$+++ u9030 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ DURNFORD +++$+++ Lord Chelmsford 
seems to want me to stay back with my Basutos.

L666372 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ I think Chelmsford wants a good man on the border Why he fears a flanking attack and requires a steady Commander in reserve.
```

So for example, I want the first line to be outputted as `Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?`

instead of the current string `L666256 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?`

How can I do that?

Comment: SO is not a "write me software" service

Comment: Are you sure you need regex? `split()` may be enough.

Comment: Try [`^.*\+{3}\$\+{3}\s*` replace with nothing](https://regex101.com/r/HzuEQn/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use regular expressions and the re module.

```
string = "L666256 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?"
regex = r"^.*\+{3}\$\+{3}\s*"
re.sub(regex, "", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read you text file and replace the exact character using string methods.

Example:

```
txt = """L666256 +++$+++ u9034 +++$+++ m616 +++$+++ VEREKER +++$+++ Colonel Durnford... William Vereker. I hear you 've been seeking Officers?"""

print(' '.join(txt.split(" +++$+++ ")))
```

or just use `replace()`

```
print(txt.replace(" +++$+++ ", " "))
```